# How to solve for matrix A in AX = B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm given the following linear system:
$$x+my+(m-1)z = m+1$$
$$(2-3m)y+(-2m+3)z = -3m$$
$$m(2-m)y+m(3-m)z = m-m^2$$

I am also given the following:
$$B_m = \begin{bmatrix}m+1 \\ -3m \\ m-m^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$$

How can I find $$A_m$$ such that $$A_m * X = B_m$$? I know how to solve for X when given A and B (inverse A * B), but not sure how to solve for A here.

Comment: Gaussian Elimination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B_m$ here is the column matrix of the right-hand side of the linear system. Also, $x,y,z$ are the variables of the system. So we can get $A_m$ by just factoring out the varibles and keeping the constant of the left-hand side of the linear system.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x & m & m-1\\
0 & 2-3m & -2m+3 \\
0 & m(2-m) & m(3-m)
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
m+1\\
-3m\\
m-m^2
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\therefore A_m=\begin{bmatrix}
x & m & m-1\\
0 & 2-3m & -2m+3 \\
0 & m(2-m) & m(3-m)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

For example, in the second equation, the third variable $z$ is multiplied by $-2m+3$, so the entry in the second row and third column of $A$ is $-2m+3$.